# How to deactivate an alphanumeric key after pressing it once?

Tags: java, swing, keyevent

I'm making a swing program using `KeyEventDispatcher`. What I need is that once I've pressed a key on the keyboard, action assigned to the key is not available the second time key is pressed. In a way, it's like setting `setEnabled()` of a `JButton` to `false` after using it once.

Comment: Store if the action has been performed. Don't perform it again.

Comment: can't you remove that action?if not create a Map<String,Boolean> and check if it was activated

Comment: Can you show some code of how you are doing this? You maybe can just dettach the action listener.

Comment: show a SSCCE that demonstrates what you are doing and how it doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 0):

So you use the key and pass it to method that performs the corresponding action.
After the actions has been requested/ performed, remove it from the list or mark it as unavailable. When it gets called again, there's no available action so it does nothing.
Your store would just be a hash / dictionary of some description keyed by the character / keycode, from the keypress handler.

Or instead of actually performing the action it returns it. In the cases where it's already been done, return null, or a do nothing ( or may be a beep or some such).

Either way, delegate all the control of actions to a another class.
Gives you all sort of options, especially if you use an interface, you could inject different action handlers into the ui.

Answer (score 0):

As each key is triggered, add its `KeyStroke` or key code to a `List`. Compare the incoming values to this list (`contains`). Ignore it if you find it...